# Find the conditions on $a,b$ and $c$ such that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Find the conditions on $a,b$ and $c$ such that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.
Given:$$f(x)=a|\sin(x)|+be^{|x|}+c|x|^3$$
My try: I first verified that the function is continuous at $x=0$. This was trivial. Then for values of $x$ sufficiently close to 0, we can write
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
a\sin(x)+be^x+cx^3  & \text{when $x>0$}\\
b  & \text{when $x=0$}\\
-a\sin(x)+be^{-x}-cx^3  & \text{when $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, on taking the derivative of $f(x)$, I got
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
a\cos(x)+be^x+3cx^2 & \text{when $x>0$}\\
-a\cos(x)-be^{-x}-3cx^2 & \text{when $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, on equating the right hand derivative to the left hand derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$, I got the conditions on $a,b$ and $c$ as:
$$a+b=0;\ \ \  c\ \ \text{can be any real number}$$
But the answer to the problem is given as$$a=b=0;\ \ \ c\ \ \text{can be any real number}$$
Now, since the case $a=b=0$ is one of the possibilities of the answer I got, in order to verify my answer, I took $a=1,\ b=-1,\ c=5$ and computed the derivative at $x=0$ on WolframAlpha, but the answer that I got was that $f'(0)$ is undefined.

Where am I going wrong??

Thanks for any answers!!

Comment: a+b=0 is absolutely right. Check your inputs in Wolfram alpha again

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%7Csinx%7C-e%5E%7Cx%7C%2B5%7Cx%7C%5E3+when+x%3D0

Comment: Plotting the function and it's derivative on desmos also gave the same answer..$f'(0)$ is undefined..

Comment: Try this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate+f%28x%29%3D%7Csinx%7C-e%5E%7Cx%7C%2B5%7Cx%7C%5E3+when++x%3D0

Comment: This is crazy! What's going on??....and what about Desmos?

Comment: Hang on..I think there is a bug in WolframAlpha...check this out: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+f%28x%29%3D%7Cx%7C+when+x%3D0

Comment: But this works:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%7Cx%7C+when+x%3D0

Comment: I think WA is calculating derivative from general f'(x) and not checking differentiability conditions. it appears as if it goes by domain of derivatives. check this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D%7Csinx%7C-e%5E%7Cx%7C%2B5%7Cx%7C%5E3

Comment: Hmm..it may be the same case with Desmos..but is there any error in my method? because the book that I'm using also says $a=b=0$ is the answer, It is a multiple choice question by the way..

Comment: Your answer/method is absolutely correct

Comment: Well..I don't see why the answer dosen't match..yea..maybe WA goes by the domain of the derivatives....But thanks for your help anyways!